# Spring Cloud gateway custom routing not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm trying to build a spring cloud gateway server to provide custom routes to the 2 microservices that I have built.

Gateway server pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.geminibank</groupId>
    <artifactId>apigateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>apigateway</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

gateway server properties file

```
server.port=8090
spring.application.name = apigateway

spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled = true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lowerCaseServiceId = true

management.endpoint.gateway.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,gateway

eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address = true
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.fetch-registry = true
eureka.client.register-with-eureka = true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:8082/eureka/
```

Gateway Config

```
@Configuration
public class GatewayConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public RouteLocator customeRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
         RouteLocator routes = builder.routes()
                .route("profile-service", p -> p
                        .path("/api/profile/**")
                        .uri("lb://PROFILESERVICE"))
                .route("account-service", p -> p
                        .path("/api/account/**")
                        .uri("lb://ACCOUNTSSERVICE"))
                .build();
         routes.getRoutes().log();
         return routes;
         

    }

}
```

When I start the server and check for routes (at actuator/gateway/routes I get this

```
[
    {
        "predicate": "Paths: [/api/profile/**], match trailing slash: true",
        "route_id": "profile-service",
        "filters": [],
        "uri": "lb://PROFILESERVICE",
        "order": 0
    },
    {
        "predicate": "Paths: [/api/account/**], match trailing slash: true",
        "route_id": "account-service",
        "filters": [],
        "uri": "lb://ACCOUNTSSERVICE",
        "order": 0
    },
    {
        "predicate": "Paths: [/profileservice/**], match trailing slash: true",
        "metadata": {
            "jmx.port": "51067",
            "management.port": "8083"
        },
        "route_id": "ReactiveCompositeDiscoveryClient_PROFILESERVICE",
        "filters": [
            "[[RewritePath /profileservice/?(?<remaining>.*) = '/${remaining}'], order = 1]"
        ],
        "uri": "lb://PROFILESERVICE",
        "order": 0
    },
    {
        "predicate": "Paths: [/accountsservice/**], match trailing slash: true",
        "metadata": {
            "jmx.port": "51001",
            "management.port": "8084"
        },
        "route_id": "ReactiveCompositeDiscoveryClient_ACCOUNTSSERVICE",
        "filters": [
            "[[RewritePath /accountsservice/?(?<remaining>.*) = '/${remaining}'], order = 1]"
        ],
        "uri": "lb://ACCOUNTSSERVICE",
        "order": 0
    },
    {
        "predicate": "Paths: [/apigateway/**], match trailing slash: true",
        "metadata": {
            "jmx.port": "59682",
            "management.port": "8090"
        },
        "route_id": "ReactiveCompositeDiscoveryClient_APIGATEWAY",
        "filters": [
            "[[RewritePath /apigateway/?(?<remaining>.*) = '/${remaining}'], order = 1]"
        ],
        "uri": "lb://APIGATEWAY",
        "order": 0
    }
]
```

When I'm trying to hit the custom api i.e either `/api/account` or `/api/profile`, I'm getting a 404 error, but the same request works fine when i replace `/api/account` with `/accountsservice`.

I've tried disabling `lower-case-service-id`, but it still works that way only. I'm not able to use the custom routes that I have defined.

Please help.

Comment: Does `http://<ACCOUNTSERVICE:port>/api/account` work? Does that path exist on the service?

Comment: no. I've created /api/account to work as a prefix for accountservice endpoints

Comment: what i want to achieve is that if i hit `http://localhost:8090/api/account/{endpoint}` , then gateway should redirect that request to `http://localhost:8090/ACCOUNTSSERVICE/{endpoint}`

Comment: Gateway doesn't change the path by default. If the path is different on the downstream service you'll need to use a filter, like SetPath or similar